# 2 applications and a Windows Service using WCF. Who is server and who is client?

Tags: wcf, server, client, named-pipes

I have a basic question to this scenario.

First some details:

The applications "App One" and "App Two" should not communicate directly, they should communicate using a service in the middle. Communication should be over named pipes.

One of the application "App One" is the master.

Actions of "App One"
- ask for a list of something from "App Two" and get the list as answer
- Sends Data to "App Two"

Answer (score 0):

In all of the scenarios you have mentioned the requester is always the client and the other is considered as the server. So what this means is that both the "Apps" mentioned here act as a client and a server, depending on who the requester is.